# How to turn a website into black&white

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I use twitter bootstrap v 3, and have a student that has asked that I display my website in black and white only.

Q: Is there a quick way to turn off all the colors or do I need to override each color that's in bootstrap-theme.css?

Maybe I could use the !important rule and override everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` element to apply a style to every element on the page, for example to make all the font on the page black use:

```
* 
{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: But what about specificity?

Comment: Oh! I could turn css off altogether!

Answer (score 0):

I would say put a condition around the css tags:

```
if usr has defined they own css file, then
use the users css file
else 
use the default css file
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, however, if you only need the site to be "black and white" temporarily, you might try a JavaScript bookmarklet.

For instance, to transform your site to gray scale without affecting the site itself, you might try this:

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.body.setAttribute('style','filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale");-webkit-filter:grayscale(1);filter:grayscale(1);');
})();
```

If stored in bookmarklet form this can turn *any* site into gray scale.

To go back to the original way use this:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.setAttribute('style','');})();
```